# Markdown Syntax Highlighting change in .10 vs <.10 in MS VSCODE

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

Has anyone else noticed the change in syntax highlighting (inline, not the generated) for markdown in the newer .10 release for visual studio code.  Maybe I am just being picky, but it is driving me mad that the lists are not colored anymore. Is there a way to revert the inline highlighting to the prior style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regression got fixed and will be available in our next update mid of December: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/273